# FormFlattening doesnt have an effect when saving a new PDF file with iTextSharper

Tags: itext

I am trying to edit (fill in text form fields) inside an existing PDF document. But I would like to save it and leave the option to edit later by a user.

After using the AcroFields (from PdfStamper) to set fields' values, i set the FormFlattening to False, but after I open the new PDF, I cannot edit the fields.

How do I leave the file unlocked?

Please note that the original file is fully editable.

Thanks.

Comment: Please supply self-contained example code and a sample document.

Answer (score 0):

i'm in same situation...used code is:

```
using (FileStream outFile = new FileStream("c:\\result.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("c:\\D300.pdf");
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outFile);


            AcroFields fields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
            //rest of the code here
            fields.SetField("an_r", "2013");
            fields.SetField("luna_r", "2");

            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
            pdfStamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
```